# Does having multiple Google Apps Script projects slow down execution time?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-project

I am creating a new Google Apps Script projects for clients of mine. These projects are only owned and managed by my single Google Account. These Apps Script projects are duplicates of each other with changes in document IDs. I have a total of 6 Apps Script projects, and I am looking to add 20 more clients (so 20 more projects).

Will this slow down the execution time on my end as well as my clients end? Does each project run on different servers? Does the amount of project on 1 Google Account play a role in execution speed?

[image: Screenshot of my Google Apps Script Projects]

Comment: I'm guessing that the performance is not affected at all.  But if the code is running from your account, then it goes against your quota limits.  And Apps Script isn't scalable.  You can't somehow get more quota.  If your code were published as an add-on, then the code would run as if it were on the users account, and go against their quota.  Add-on users can't see add-on code even though it's using their quota.  The code probably only runs on different servers if the users were running the code from their account, and were in different geographic locations.

Comment: You can view the duration of the different script executions in [the Apps Script dashboard's execution tab](https://script.google.com/home/executions), you can compare the executions times historically as you add new projects, and you should arrive at an empirical conclusion. Can you see any relevant differences in same script executions as you add more scripts (projects) ?

Comment: That makes sense Alan Wells. And I have not noticed any difference in executions timing when adding more project Aerials. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @Alan Wells the execution time is not affected by the amount of projects in your account, however your Apps Script quota limits apply to the sum of all your projects.

And if the code were a running as an Add-On it would probably do so on different servers as the users would be running the code from their account, and likely in different geographic locations.

But to summarize:

- If the code is running from your account, then it goes against your quota limits.
- Apps Script isn't scalable. You can't somehow get more quota.
- If your code were published as an Add-On, then the code would run as if it were on the users account, and go against their quota.
- Add-On users can't see the project code even though it's using their quota.
- You can view the duration of the different script executions in the [Apps Script dashboard's execution tab](https://script.google.com/home/executions).